# Invalid number of arguments error in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

Please let me know whether there is anything wrong in the insert statement of the below query. It is giving me 'invalid number of arguments' errors

```
    create or replace PROCEDURE adm_getMaxTableIdLimited
    (
    v_TableName IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
    v_TableIDColumnName IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
    v_MaxTableId OUT NUMBER
    )
    AS
    v_Limit NUMBER(10,0);
    v_SQLStatement VARCHAR2(255);

    BEGIN
   v_Limit:= 99999 ;
   v_MaxTableId:= 0 ;
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP TABLE  TempResult';
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'CREATE GLOBAL TEMPORARY TABLE TempResult
   (
     Result NUMBER(10,0) 
   )';

    v_SQLStatement:= 'Insert INTO TempResult(Result) SELECT max(' || v_TableIDColumnName || ')    
    FROM ' || v_TableName || ' WHERE ' || v_TableIDColumnName || ' <= ' || CAST(v_limit AS 
    VARCHAR2) || ';';
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQLStatement;
     EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT Result INTO v_MaxTableId FROM TempResult' ;
     IF ( v_MaxTableId = v_Limit ) THEN
        v_MaxTableId := -1 ;
    ELSE
       v_MaxTableId := v_MaxTableId + 1 ;
    END IF;  
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE ' TRUNCATE TABLE TempResult ';
   END;
```

Comment: Why don't you try printing the sql query you are generating?

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I was supposed to enter he correct table name and columnname as input parameters ,which I wasn't doing. But now after entering correct data , it is giving 'invalid character' error. And this was the table I was referring to :

Comment: CREATE TABLE NECHO_APP.ACCESSLEVEL 
(
  ACCESSLEVELID NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL 
, ACCESSLEVELNAME VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, ACCESSLEVELVALUE NUMBER(*, 0) NOT NULL 
, CREATESTAMP TIMESTAMP(6) NOT NULL 
, MODSTAMP TIMESTAMP(6) 
, MODUSER VARCHAR2(50 BYTE) NOT NULL 
, CONSTRAINT PKACCESSLEVEL PRIMARY KEY 
  (
    ACCESSLEVELID 
  )
  ENABLE 
) 
LOGGING 
TABLESPACE "USERS" 
PCTFREE 10 
INITRANS 1 
STORAGE 
( 
  INITIAL 65536 
  NEXT 1048576 
  MINEXTENTS 1 
  MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 
  BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT 
);   I tried entering ACCESSLEVEL as table name and ACCESSLEVELID as column name

Comment: Look at your create table statement; all the numbers are incorrect.

Comment: P.S. why are you creating and dropping global temporary tables? The point of them is that you _don't_ have to do this.

Comment: Following on from Ben, why are you using any kind of table at all for this? Why not just select the value?

Answer (score 3):

You don't need a temporary table at all. And your code can be considerably simplified:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE adm_getMaxTableIdLimited
(
    v_TableName IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    v_TableIDColumnName IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL,
    v_MaxTableId OUT NUMBER
)
AS
    v_Limit NUMBER;

BEGIN
    v_Limit:= 99999 ;

    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE
        'SELECT MAX(' || v_TableIDColumnName || ') FROM '
        || v_TableName || ' WHERE ' || v_TableIDColumnName || ' <= :limit'
    INTO v_MaxTableId
    USING v_Limit;

    IF v_MaxTableId = v_Limit THEN
        v_MaxTableId := -1;
    ELSE
       v_MaxTableId := v_MaxTableId + 1;
    END IF;  
END;
```

BTW: The current problem in your code is:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT Result INTO v_MaxTableId FROM TempResult';
```

The correct line would be:

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'SELECT Result FROM TempResult' INTO v_MaxTableId;
```

Comment: Thanks. Working like a charm.

Comment: Might like to wrap the MAX() in a Coalesce(Max(...),0) to be safe. The logic that tests against the limit could be pushed into the SQL also.

Answer (score 0):

First off, it seems very, very unlikely that you want to dynamically drop and create your temporary table.  A global temporary table is just that-- global.  The table definition is visible to other sessions unlike what you might have grown accustomed to in other databases.  Just like permanent tables, you would create the temporary table once when you're installing the application.  Dropping and recreating the table won't work correctly in a multi-user environment.

Second, there does not appear to be any reason to use a temporary table here.  You can just dynamically generate the `SELECT` statement and store the result in a local variable.

Third, your `INSERT` statement should not have a semicolon at the end.  That's what is generating the ORA-00911: invalid character error.

Fourth, your dynamic `SELECT` statement should not have an `INTO`.  That `INTO` clause needs to be part of the `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE`, not the SQL statement.

My guess, therefore, is that you want something like

```
create or replace PROCEDURE adm_getMaxTableIdLimited
(
  v_TableName IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
  v_TableIDColumnName IN VARCHAR2 DEFAULT NULL ,
  v_MaxTableId OUT NUMBER
)
AS
  v_Limit NUMBER(10,0) := 99999;
  v_SQLStatement VARCHAR2(255);
BEGIN
  v_SQLStatement := 
   'SELECT max(' || v_TableIDColumnName || ')  ' ||
   '  FROM ' || v_TableName || 
   ' WHERE ' || v_TableIDColumnName || ' <= :1';
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_SQLStatement 
    INTO v_MaxTableId
   USING v_Limit;
 IF ( v_MaxTableId = v_Limit ) THEN
    v_MaxTableId := -1 ;
ELSE
   v_MaxTableId := v_MaxTableId + 1 ;
END IF;
```

END;

Why are you creating this procedure in the first place, though?  It appears to be used to return the next value of a key to insert into the table.  If that's what you're doing, you need to reconsider your approach.  Generating dynamic SQL that scans the primary key index for the maximum value is much less efficient than using a sequence.  It also doesn't work correctly outside of a toy system where you can guarantee that there is only one user.  In a real system, multiple sessions will get the same value and try to insert rows with the same key.  One of the two will block on the `INSERT` and eventually get a duplicate key error.

Comment: Thanks. your code is working perfectly. Actually I am just migrating the procedures from sql server to oracle, changing the commands to match the oracle syntax, and correcting the errors.

Comment: @SameekKundu - Blindly porting from SQL Server to Oracle is unlikely to produce good results.  There are lots of differences between the databases that require you to approach problems differently.  There are lots of times that you'll use temporary tables in SQL Server that you would not want to use them when porting the code to Oracle.